# User's profile picture is not appearing fully in the review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, imgur

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/rujordan) user's image in the recent reviewer's queue,

[image]

It appears partially. I tried it in both chrome and Firefox. But the profile picture of that user looks fine and the popup of that queue image also seems good.

Only a minor issue, but needs to be fixed.

I'll add any other instances with same issue if I got them.

Comment: Oh hey, that's me!! I've been wondering why it only half loads. Ain't I gorgeous?

Comment: @RUJordan don't flatter yourself, we haven't seen the bottom half yet

Comment: @RUJordan, could you review a post(not a suggested edit) now? We can got that issue.

Comment: @Azik done and done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imgur mega-failed at resizing the picture. It just needed to be re-uploaded.

Comment: I rather like it, it's taking my selfie to a whole new level.

Comment: Issue fixed, retag needed.